# Display wikipage(default.aspx) in mobile view

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, wiki, mobile

Recently I deployed a site using sharepoint foundation 2010 sp2.

The site has anonymous access to entire site. I developed some wiki pages using wikipage library. it's looking fine in desktop ,laptop,ipad,tab's.

But coming to mobile view the wikipages are not displaying. But I want to show the wiki page's in mobile view also.

So is there any setting required to set up for that? SP 2010 Foundation SP2